# Outlook 2013 is marking all messages read when it is opened

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, unread-mail

I have outlook 2013 and it is marking every message in my inbox read the second I open the program. I have no way of knowing which emails I have actually read or not. I can't figure out any reason that it would be doing this. Any ideas?

I have played with the reading pane settings and everything else I can think of. No matter what I do they never stay as unread for more than a couple seconds and then I just have to go by memory if I have seen an email or not.

Comment: If you disable all plug-ins and/or try Outlook's safe mode (Outlook /safe) does it still do it?

Comment: Do you have any other devices checking that email account (like say, your phone?)

Comment: There are two email addresses coming into the same outlook i.e. "name@" and "billing@". The billing is received by two separate people but not the other. They aren't checked anywhere else. I will check the plug-ins and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Turns out that the account had two setup. There was a name@ as a POP/SMTP and a name@ as a IMAP/SMTP. When the extra was removed the problem went away. As well as all address book contacts. So for others dealing with this in the future, be sure to copy those contacts somewhere before deleting the extra email setup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get into "Advanced View Settings: Messages".
Go to the View menu (ribbon) and on the left side of the ribbon click "View Settings" in the "Current View" section.

This will open up "Advanced View Settings: Messages".
Click on the "Conditional Formatting..." button.

On my PC, the top box was unchecked ("Unread messages").  Check it.
Click OK, then OK again, and you are good to go.  Messages that come into Outlook will now be deemed as unread (they'll be highlighted) until you read them.